# Python socket wont stop spam

Tags: python, sockets

I am sending a message to client but the client wont stop spamming the message

**server.py**

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
hostname = socket.gethostname()
hostip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
port = 462

server.bind((hostname, port))
server.listen(1)
print((hostip, port))

client, address = server.accept()
print("New connection!: ", address)

while True:
    data = input("Do something:")
    if data == "help":
        print("test: 'test'")
        input("Click ENTER to continue")
    elif data == "test":
        client.send("test".encode('ascii'))
    else:
        continue
```

**client.py**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 462

s.connect(('', port))
data = s.recv(1024)

while True:
    if data.decode('ascii') == "test":
        print(data.decode('ascii'))
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I hope this is what you meant

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: then why how it was before wasnt enough? it states the problem and it shows the code that probably is causing the problem

Comment: As an example, your question doesn't show the setup of `client` for the server, or where `data` comes from in the client... How can we help if we don't know what you're doing? Please provide full / minimal source code that demonstrates the problem so that we can try to help.

Comment: this is all of the code in hastebin

Comment: Can you post the complete code snippet? `client` variable is never defined in `server.py`, and what is `client.send`? Where was it defined? It's almost impossible to provide some help with such incomplete code.

Comment: its in the hastebin link I sent refresh the page

Comment: Links break.  Post the code on this site as a [mcve].

Comment: the problem is already solved....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the full example, but I think I can see where the problem is.

Where/when do you actually read/receive the data from the socket in the client.py?

Because it looks like you received the data, saved it in the in the "data" variable and then you keep looping forever **decoding** this data, not **reading from socket**.

So I think you need to move your while loop in client.py outside, so that the read/receive from socket method is **inside** your loop, not outside as it appears it is now.

Edit: Yup, from the full code that you posted I can see that indeed, this should fix your problem.

Comment: the code in hastebin is all of my code not including the imports